# Why DecimalFormat displays ▯ instead of commas?

Tags: java, plugins, format, minecraft

I'm developing a plugin for a Minecraft server and wanted to use DecimalFormat to have a nice display.

BUT, with this code:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###,###.##");
p.sendMessage(df.format(amount));
```

It displays things like that : 10▯450.23 instead of 10,450.23

Why?? If you have any ideas don't hesitate.

Comment: Is the locale set?

Comment: @NomadMaker oh yeah the local wasn't set thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DecimalFormat has [Locale-sensitive formatting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html).

It is possible that the system you are launching your Minecraft server on is in different locale.

If you want to get DecimalFormat for different locale (for example standard English locale), do it like this:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) nf;
df.applyPattern("#,###,###,###.##");
p.sendMessage(df.format(amount));
```

You can also change Locale for instance of JVM, so you won't have to change locale to ENGLISH everytime:

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Be careful with that though.

Answer (score -1):

I tested the exact code you send, and it worked perfectly fine for me! I don't really know where the issue is? Try using the standard Minecraft texture pack.